# Can't update quantity to cart

Tags: template, addtocart

I put the form for the checkbox how many items the user want to buy:

```
<?php $haveProds = $this->getHaveProducts();?>
            <?php if($_product->isAvailable() && $haveProds) { ?>
                <div class="mergeContainer">
                    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
                    <label for="qty">Wählen Sie Ihre gewünschte Menge</label>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <select name="qty" id="qty">
                      <?php $i = 1 ?>
                      <?php do { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i?>">
                          <?php echo $i?>
                          <?php $i++ ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php } while ($i <= (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getMaxSaleQty()) ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            <?php }?>
```

from my app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view-adopted.phtml
to .../view/addtocart.phtml

so the user will be able to change the quantity directly above the add-to-cart button in the right box.

After that the selected value of the dropdown won't be overtaken in the cart anymore. If I click on "add to cart" now, just one item is added.

Unfortunately I can't find the function that reads this value. Can anyone help me?

Best
Vanessa

Comment: if you use the developer tools in your browser, what is the url that the add to cart button is using, including the parameters.

Comment: onclick function is: productAddToCartForm.submit(this), URL is: `http://lenas-tulpenbaum.localhost/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xlbmFzLXR1bHBlbmJhdW0ubG9jYWxob3N0L3Jvc2UuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/381/`

Comment: Is this qty drop down inside the add to cart form? otherwise it wont work

Comment: Ah.. no, the form-declaration was still at the old place - I took the form now to the sidebox with the dropdown. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that we have an answer here.

What you should do is have this quantity field inside the add to cart form so that the button action `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` will be able to load the requested quantity information and pass this to the cart itself.